# How come by image won’t change after I press the key?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

```py
import pygame import sys

pygame.init()#We always need to initalize our pygame IN EVERY
PROJECT/FILE

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))# Here win is representing
"window" for our screen which we have set at 500 by 480

pygame.display.set_caption("Dragon Ball Z Mini-game")#We are giving our Window/Screen a name

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image0 - t.png'), pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image1 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image2 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image3 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_right_image4 - t.png')] walkLeft =
[pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image0 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image1 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image2 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image3 - t.png'),
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku_left_image4 - t.png')] bg =
pygame.image.load('image/bg2.jpg') char =
pygame.image.load('image/young_goku - standing - t.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/kiblast.wav") hitSound =
pygame.mixer.Sound("image/Bomb+1.wav")
#bulletSound.play() music = pygame.mixer.music.load("image/16 - Dragon Ball Z - title song.mp3") pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

score = 0

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 10:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if not (self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
        # pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def hit(self):
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 410
        self.walkCount = 0
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('Papyrus', 100)
        text = font1.render('Attcked!', 1, (255, 0, 0))
        win.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 2), 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        i = 0
        while i < 200:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            i += 1
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    i = 201
                    pygame.quit()


class projectile():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, (244, 232, 104), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        ki = pygame.image.load("image/ki.png")
        win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
        ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
        win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))

class projectile2():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        ki = pygame.image.load("image/b4.png")
        win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))
        ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/b4.png")
        win.blit(ki, (self.x, self.y))




class enemy(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load("image/R1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R2E.png"),
                 pygame.image.load("image/R3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R4E.png"),
                 pygame.image.load("image/R5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R6E.png"),
                 pygame.image.load("image/R7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R8E.png"),
                 pygame.image.load("image/R9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/R10E.png"),
                 pygame.image.load("image/R11E.png")]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("image/L1E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L2E.png"),
                pygame.image.load("image/L3E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L4E.png"),
                pygame.image.load("image/L5E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L6E.png"),
                pygame.image.load("image/L7E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L8E.png"),
                pygame.image.load("image/L9E.png"), pygame.image.load("image/L10E.png"),
                pygame.image.load("image/L11E.png")]

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
                self.walkCount = 0

            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 128, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            # pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        print('hit')


class enemy2():
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-standing-T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-moving_T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-moving_T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-move_right-T.gif")]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite-standing-T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left-T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left-T.gif"),
pygame.image.load("image/enemy-sprite - moving_left2-T.gif")]
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.walkcount + 0 >= 10:
                self.walkcount = 0

            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 128, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount = 0

        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        print("Hit!!")
        pass

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    text = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text, (350, 10))
    goblin.draw(win)
    goblin2.draw(win)
    man.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


# mainloop font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True) man = player(200, 410, 64, 64) goblin = enemy(110, 410, 64, 64, 450) goblin2
= enemy2(50, 410, 64, 64, 450) shootLoop = 0 bullets = [] run = True while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    if goblin.visible == True:
        if man.hitbox[1] < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblin.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
                man.hit()
                score -= 5

    if goblin2.visible == True:
        if man.hitbox[1] < goblin2.hitbox[1] + goblin2.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > goblin2.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin2.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin2.hitbox[0] + goblin2.hitbox[2]:
                man.hit()
                score -= 5

    if shootLoop > 0:
        shootLoop += 1
    if shootLoop > 3:
        shootLoop = 0

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[1]:
            if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
                goblin.hit()
                score += 1
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin2.hitbox[1] + goblin2.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > goblin2.hitbox[1]:
            if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin2.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < goblin2.hitbox[0] + goblin2.hitbox[2]:
                goblin2.hit()
                score += 1
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootLoop == 0:
        #bulletSound.play()
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))

        shootLoop = 1

**Here where am trying to see if my image changes when i press a key button**
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootLoop == 0:
        ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
        win.blit(ki_stance, (0, 0))
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) < 3.30:
            bullets.append(projectile2(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount = 0

    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Well,please edit your post with a correct format.And it seems all of your code is post.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing what `redrawGameWindow` does, is to draw the background in the window:

> ```
> def redrawGameWindow():
>    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
>    # [...]
> ```

All what is drawn before calling `redrawGameWindow` is "invisible", because the back covers the entire screen:

> ```
> if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootLoop == 0:
>    ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
>    win.blit(ki_stance, (0, 0))  # <----- "INVISIBLE"
>
> # [...]
>
> redrawGameWindow() # <---- because it is covered here
> ```

---

Load all the images at initialization, before the application loop:

```py
ki = pygame.image.load("image/ki.png")
ki_stance = pygame.image.load("image/goku-ki.png")
```

Change the class `projectile`, `stance` is a new argument to the constructor of the class. You don't need the class `projectile2` at all, (delete `projectile2`):

```py
class projectile():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing, stance):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing
        self.stance = stance

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, (244, 232, 104), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        image = ki_stance if self.stance else ki
        win.blit(image, (self.x, self.y))
```

When <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, the spawn a projectile:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootLoop == 0  and len(bullets) < 5:
    #bulletSound.play()
    facing = -1 if man.left else 1
    x, y = round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2)
    bullets.append(projectile(x, y, 6, (0, 0, 0), facing, False))
    shootLoop = 1

if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootLoop == 0  and len(bullets) < 3.30:
    facing = -1 if man.left else 1 
    x, y = round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2)
    bullets.append(projectile(x, y, 6, (0, 0, 0), facing, True))
    shootLoop = 1
```

---

If you want to show a different sprite for the player, when <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, then you have to do it in `player.draw`. e.g:

```py
b4Image = pygame.image.load("image/b4.png")
```

```py
class player(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 10:
            self.walkCount = 0

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            win.blit(b4Image, (self.x, self.y))

        elif not (self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
```

Comment: So would I have to my code in the redrawGameWindow? @Rabbid76

Comment: so what am trying to do is every time I Press the key “a” on my keyboard i want it to change into the image of my player firing the shot to make it more clearer imagine Player in standing mode then I Press a he shoots the shot but with image showing him shooting the shot do you get me? @Rabbid76

Comment: Yes I would want to spawn a projectile with different image so every time I Press a I would want the image to change while projectile is being shot

Comment: No not the projectile but my Player in my game when I press a he shots his ki blast but I went him in the image of him shooting the ki blast@Rabbid76

Comment: How can I get my image of my character to move or to change  when he fire his ki blast and b4.png is the image of Goku in his stance of doing the Kamamaha

Comment: None of them seem to be working am trying to put the code in the draw function yet my character won’t appear anymore?

Comment: @RalphPerez *"None of them seem to be working"* - what does not work? That is one answer. You have to implement all the changes in the answer.